# how to define an array of chars in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have this code and it's compiling correctly :

```
char classfname[512] = "classifiers/cabmodel_VOC05motorbikes.xml";
strcpy(classfname,argv[i]);
```

but when I tried to define an array contains strings from the same size of the above size 
and with your all help it didn't work !

```
std::vector<std::string> classfname = {
    "classifiers/cabmodel_VOC05motorbikes.xml",
    "classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst100_VOC06person01train5_orienthistmod.xml" ,
    "classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst40_VOC06cat01train5_trainval_orienthistmod_nopert_facereg.xml",
    "classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst100_VOC06bicycle01train5_trainval_orienthistmod.xml",
    "classifiers/cabmodel_VOC06carside.xml",
    "classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst100_VOC06horse01train5_trainval_orienthistmod_randsel0100.xml"
    };

char *classfname[6]={-----}
std::vector<std::string> classfname;
classfname.push_back(",,,");
```

with the function `strcpy(classfname,argv[i]);`

I got the error:

```
Error   2   error C2664: 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'char *
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you sure this is the code you have? The error seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: This is not the code you have a problem with, [it compiles fine](http://ideone.com/BrHcd). Also, an IntelliSense error is *not* a compiler error. IntelliSense sometimes bugs out and display nonsense, so I wouldn't rely on it too much for errors. Just hit F7 to compile the code and come back with the real error message (and the real code you use).

Comment: Note that your function prototype: `xmlLoadModel(const::std string &file,Model &model)` isn't valid... maybe it is: `xmlLoadModel(const std::string &file, Model &model)`.

Comment: It appears that the code you list would not produce the error you posted. Please post a small, complete program that demonstrates your error. http://sscce.org

Comment: @Xeo and Rob: The code does not compile fine, it has errors, one of which _might_ be related to his problem.

Comment: @MooingDuck - perhaps you are right. Let me rephrase. The code that the OP posted is hopelessly incomplete and inaccurate. PureSoul, please post a complete program code that demonstrates the error you see. (hint: `const::std string` does not name a type.)

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me here , so kind of you .
I don't know how it worked with you !! but It's still giving me those errors , and that function "xmlLoadModel" is not mine 
actually the code was compiling with a simple char name[512]='....'
but I need to define an array ,,,,

Comment: the whole code is so huge !
I've posted the code that is related to the errors .

Comment: @PureSoul - please reduce the size of your program to the smallest possible complete program that demonstrates the error. We don't need to see your original program, a small demonstration will do just fine. See http://sscce.org/ for more information. Failing that, please copy-paste (**DO NOT MERELY REYPTE**) the line that produces the error. (You made typographical errors in the code above.)

Comment: ok, I will and I'm so so sorry :$

Comment: @Rob Is it good now ? I'm new here :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use `const char*` like this:

```
const char *classfname[7]={"classifiers/cabmodel_VOC05motorbikes.xml",
    "classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst100_VOC06person01train5_orienthistmod.xml" ,
    "classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst40_VOC06cat01train5_trainval_orienthistmod_nopert_facereg.xml",
    "classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst100_VOC06bicycle01train5_trainval_orienthistmod.xml",
    "classifiers/cabmodel_VOC06carside.xml",
    "classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst100_VOC06horse01train5_trainval_orienthistmod_randsel0100.xml",
};
```

Also if you want to have a `std::vector` containing these strings use can initialize it with the following statement:

```
const std::vector<std::string> classfname_vector(classfname, classfname + 7);
```

One more thing I noticed is that you declared an array with 7 elements but initialized it only with 6 string literals.

Answer (score 3):

Converting string literals to a `char*` is no longer allowed, since it was never safe.  Instead, make an array of `const char*`.  (Although I'm not 100% positive this is the cause of your error, but your code doesn't match your error well, I think you changed something to put it on SO).  `std::string` has a constructor from `const char*`, so this should work fine.

Also, it's good to note that `(const::std string &` is not right, so we *know* you changed stuff when you posted it here.  Don't do that, or we can't help you much at all.  It should be `(const std::string&`.

Also, MrC64 notes that you should use RAII instead of raw arrays and pointers.  It's easier to use, and harder to mess up.

```
std::vector<std::string> classfname = {
    "classifiers/cabmodel_VOC05motorbikes.xml",
    "classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst100_VOC06person01train5_orienthistmod.xml" ,
    "classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst40_VOC06cat01train5_trainval_orienthistmod_nopert_facereg.xml",
    "classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst100_VOC06bicycle01train5_trainval_orienthistmod.xml",
    "classifiers/cabmodel_VOC06carside.xml",
    "classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst100_VOC06horse01train5_trainval_orienthistmod_randsel0100.xml"
    };
```

If your compiler can't handle that syntax yet (many can't), use the code that Mr_C64 suggested.

**[EDIT]**  You have changed your question dramatically to be a completely different question.  Generally this is bad, because anyone who comes to this page looking for answers will see that our answers don't match your question anymore.  If you have additional questions, you should use the search feature, or make a new question page.

Now your code has a `std::vector` of `std::strings`.  Treat a `std::string` like you would an `int`.  Just copy it, or pass it around with no worries.  You don't have do use a special function to copy a `int`, so you don't need a special function to copy a string.  Just do `std::string newstring = classfname[0];` to get a copy of the string at index `0` in the array `classfname`.

Your "old" code makes an array of chars initialized to a string literal, and over-rights it with the input from `argv[i]`  The best way to do that code is:

```
std::string classfname = "classifiers/cabmodel_VOC05motorbikes.xml";
classfname = argv[i];
```

If you just want to make an array of each of the arguments, that's easy:

```
int main() {int argc, const char** argv) { 
    std::vector<std::string> classfname(argv, argv+argc);
```

Comment: Or just an array of std::string and not touch char* at all.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Edited answer while you posted that :D

Comment: thanks for answering me , I tried it and for bad i get same errors : 

`code` strcpy(classfname[i],argv[i]);
Error 2 error C2664: 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'char *' 
 6 IntelliSense: no instance of function "strcpy" matches the argument list

Comment: well, if you use RAII, you probably want to use it all the way.  One doesn't need to call `strcpy` on a `std::string.  Either way, your immediate problem was caused by `const char*`.  Did you try that?

Comment: if you mean :

`code` const char* classfname ={ ------   }
yes I tried it too  ! didn't work , same errors

Comment: Mr @mooingDuck yes, I tried it and it didn't work ! 
what its problem :(
I've tried all what you've all suggested but all didn't work !

Comment: @PureSoul: rewriting your question like that is bad form, since our answers don't match the question anymore.  Anyway, I added more information to my answer.

Comment: @PureSoul: Please remember to upvote helpful answers, downvote unhelpful answers, and mark one as "accepted as best answer" via the checkmark to the upper left of each answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a "raw" C array:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> classfname;
classfname.push_back("classifiers/cabmodel_VOC05motorbikes.xml");
classfname.push_back("classifiers/cabmodel_interm_nst100_VOC06person01train5_orienthistmod.xml");
...
```

`std::vector` overloads `operator[]`, so your call `xmlloadmodel(classfname[i],model);` should work.

Comment: And now you just need to solve the issue of static initialization in C++03 and this would be a nice answer.

Comment: I tried it (vector definition )and I got these errors :

`code`
Error 2 error C2664: 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'char *' 

 6 IntelliSense: no instance of function "strcpy" matches the argument list

Comment: @Xeo I've just tried it an I posted the errors above , still same problem !

Comment: @PureSoul: if you use std::string, you can just use operator= overload to assign a string, instead of C function strcpy().